# How to looping Flask Jinja2 form input..?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a program that can use for ticket booking, if user booking three ticket it value stored to variable **booking**, i want to make looping form input based on value from that variable **booking** .
like this form, if i booking three ticker, the form also display three input form.

[image] 
this is my **app.py**:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    booking = 3
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

**index.html**

```
    <body>
    <form action="">
        {% for contact in booking %}
        Name: <br>
        <input type="text" value="{{ contact }}"><br>
        Age: <br>
        <input type="text" value="{{ contact }}">
        {% endfor %}
    </form>
   </body>
```

so.. how to do that..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the following, this should work. Rewrite your return render template to this:

```
return render_template('index.html', booking = booking)
```

And rewrite your html as follows:

```
<body>
  <form action="">
    {% for i in range(booking) %}
      Name: <br>
      <input type="text" value="{{ contact }}"><br>
      Age: <br>
      <input type="text" value="{{ contact }}">
    {% endfor%}
   </form>
</body>
```

are you sure you want the same value for name and age btw?

Comment: thanks a lot @gittert , you save my time :)
about value you talking about, thanks, but it just for testing :)